# A generic error occurred in GDI+ During a Bitmap Save

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, bitmap, gdi+

When I run this code

```
Bitmap im = new Bitmap(600, 600, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
int height = im.Height;
int width = im.Width;
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
Point p2 = new Point(im.Size.Width, 0);
Point p3 = new Point(im.Width / 2, im.Height);
Random r = new Random();
Point p = new Point(r.Next(0, im.Size.Width), r.Next(0, im.Size.Height));
BitmapData data = im.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
const int stride = 2;
int wsrtide = data.Stride;
unsafe
{
   IntPtr osc0 = data.Scan0;
   ushort* sc0 = (ushort*)data.Scan0;
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      {
         *sc0 = 0;
         sc0 += 1;
      }
   }
   for (long i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
   {
      if (i % 1_000_000 == 0)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
      var ran = r.Next(0, 3);
      Point tp;
      switch (ran)
      {
         case 0:
            tp = new Point((p1.X + p.X) / 2, (p1.Y + p.Y) / 2);
            sc0 = (ushort*)((int)osc0 + (wsrtide * tp.Y + (tp.X * stride)));
            *sc0 = ushort.MaxValue;
            p = tp;
            break;
         case 1:
            tp = new Point((p2.X + p.X) / 2, (p2.Y + p.Y) / 2);
            sc0 = (ushort*)((int)osc0 + (wsrtide * tp.Y + (tp.X * stride)));
            *sc0 = ushort.MaxValue;
            p = tp;
            break;
         case 2:
            tp = new Point((p3.X + p.X) / 2, (p3.Y + p.Y) / 2);
            sc0 = (ushort*)((int)osc0 + (wsrtide * tp.Y + (tp.X * stride)));
            *sc0 = ushort.MaxValue;
            p = tp;
            break;
      }
   }
   im.UnlockBits(data);
   im.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\img.png");
   im.Dispose();
```

It throws where I save the bitmap

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error
>   occurred in GDI+.`

I am almost certain that this isn't caused by file permissions, when I give the program admin permission and delete the image to reset permissions it still throws. I can confirm that this code swapped with `BitmapSetPixel()` on RGB works.

My suspicion is that I'm messing up the pointers, but I'm not really sure. Also, curiously enough, it makes empty png files even though it throws.

The purpose of this code is to generate a Sierpinski triangle using the chaos game method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `Format16bppGrayScale` i don't think the `GDI` supports it very well.

Basically if you just create the Bitmap in `Format16bppGrayScale`, and save it with nothing else, it still gives the error.

I have taken the liberty to rewrite your method `Format32bppPArgb`

```
private unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var height = 600;
   var width = 600;
   var p1 = new Point(0, 0);
   var p2 = new Point(width, 0);
   var p3 = new Point(width / 2, height);
   var r = new Random();
   var p = new Point(r.Next(0, width), r.Next(0, width));

   using (var im = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
   {

      var data = im.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
      var sc0 = (int*)data.Scan0;
      var pLen = sc0 + height * width;

      var black = Color.Black.ToArgb();
      var white = Color.White.ToArgb();

      for (var pI = sc0; pI < pLen; pI++)
         *pI = black;

      for (long i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
      {
         Point tp;
         switch (r.Next(0, 3))
         {
            case 0:
               tp = new Point((p1.X + p.X) / 2, (p1.Y + p.Y) / 2);
               *(sc0 + tp.Y + tp.X * width) = white;
               p = tp;
               break;
            case 1:
               tp = new Point((p2.X + p.X) / 2, (p2.Y + p.Y) / 2);
               *(sc0 + tp.Y + tp.X * width) = white;
               p = tp;
               break;
            case 2:
               tp = new Point((p3.X + p.X) / 2, (p3.Y + p.Y) / 2);
               *(sc0 + tp.Y + tp.X * width) = white;
               p = tp;
               break;
         }
      }
      im.UnlockBits(data);
      im.Save(@"D:\img.png", ImageFormat.Png);
   }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

You can convert it after the fact if you want, add pepper and salt to taste

Also if you get rid of all the points and cache the colors this will be a bit faster

Comment: Fixed color initialization

Comment: Personally I'd go for 8bpp. Then you got a really simple one byte per pixel array, and can just put value '1' in there for white. Just need to put the two colours into the palette afterwards.

Comment: By the way, the code has X and Y switched... that should be `*(sc0 + tp.Y*width + tp.X) = white;`

Comment: @Nyerguds thanks for the heads up, and I agree with your previous comment too